# How to properly apply backpressure to PublishSubject?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactivex

I have a `PublishSubject` which emits location updates (`LatLng`):

```kotlin
val location = PublishSubject.create<LatLng>()
```

Now, I want to do something with this location, that may take some time and should be done sequentially:

```kotlin
location
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe {
        // ... CPU-heavy operation
    }
```

Only after each operation in the `subscribe` is complete, the next can run. Moreover, each update makes the previous one obsolete, so I'm only interested in the latest value. So, the subscriber should receive only the currently latest value at each update. Therefore, I thought of applying backpressure:

```kotlin
location
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSubscriber<LatLng>() {
        override fun onStart() {
            request(1)
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
            // ...
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
            // ...
        }

        override fun onNext(t: LatLng) {
            // ... CPU-heavy task
            request(1)
        }
    })
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as each `LatLng` that was emitted is delivered to the subscriber and no values are skipped, as they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `observeOn` always can buffer at least one element. You can accomplish the desired effect via `delay` though:

```java
location
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .delay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSubscriber<LatLng>() {
        override fun onStart() {
            request(1)
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
            // ...
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
            // ...
        }

        override fun onNext(t: LatLng) {
            // ... CPU-heavy task
            request(1)
        }
    })
```

Additional remarks:

1. `subscribeOn` has no practical effect with a `Subject` and can be ignored
2. The `toFlowable` is best applied close to the source to avoid flooding `delay` with items unnecessarily.
3. If you don't mind 3rd party operators, there is an [observeOnLatest](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#observabletransformersobserveonlatest) operator that can do the same thing.